# Existe uma regra específica para mensagens de commit em sistemas de versionamento como o Git?

Tags: git, versionamento

O pessoal aqui onde eu trabalho, durante um certo período, costumava não ligar para as mensagens que eles escreviam ao fazer um `git commit` por aqui.

Parece que o Git era simplesmente "um lugar para salvar as coisas para não perder as alterações".

Daí, quando precisei em um determinado dia verificar no `log` do `git` quando uma determinada alteração foi feita para fazer uma *rollback*, adivinha ... As mensagens estavam todas assim:

```
commit f337a26f387b1424e977520399c14c933d63bb90
Author: Fulano
Date:   Wed Apr 20 16:10:43 2016 -0300

    All

commit 01ef74e75a6a91e20d325e2789671f51cd26463e
Author: Fulano
Date:   Wed Apr 20 14:41:46 2016 -0300

    All

commit d13ec87f63d0149b005a24a8584819100fd7085e
Author: Fulano
Date:   Wed Apr 20 14:13:41 2016 -0300
    últimas alterações


commit 4545645sad364sdfsd4234343333333asd
Author: Fulano
Date:   Wed Apr 20 14:13:41 2016 -0300
    ddddd

commit 3158b4ce189a644020ac97b51333375f6e4c2742
Author: Wallace de Souza Vizerra <wallacemaxters@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 15 15:24:45 2016 -0300

      :)
```

Ou seja, as descrições como "enviando alterações", "all" ou "enviando tudo" não ajudam em nada a descrever o que foi feito - se é que essa mensagem serve exatamente para descrever o que foi feito, mas foi o motivo que imaginei que ela existiria no `git-commit`.

A partir desse dia que tive esse problema, combinamos que, no mínimo, descreveríamos algumas das alterações que foram feitas nas mensagens de *commit*. Não sei se esse é o caminho, mas melhorou alguma coisa depois disso.

Então, para eu obter mais organização e padronização dos meus versionamentos aqui, gostaria de saber se existe algum padrão a ser seguido (quer dizer, sugerido) para que possa ser adotado nessas mensagens.

Com eu deveria escrever minhas mensagens de *commit*?

Comment: Sim, esse último commit foi meu... Mas reparem ali um `Fri`... Ou seja, era uma Sexta-Feira... É totalmente compreensível, kkkkkkk

Comment: Creio que o padrão seja: Detalhar o máximo o que foi feito, imaginando ser uma pessoa que futuramente precisa saber disso. Talvez referenciar também a documentação da funcionalidade (Caso de Uso, História ...) se existir.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não entendi porque proteger esta pergunta. Ela só foi acessada 100x. E a nova resposta, apesar de inicialmente ter problemas, complementa a resposta que já estava aí. Veja http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2430/6036

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Talvez o problema não seja as mensagens, mas o que é feito em cada *commit*. Uma das vantagens do Git é facilitar a granulação dos *commits*. A regra é fazer uma pequena alteração, ou até outras relacionadas diretamente e fazer um *commit*, mesmo que não faça o *push* (ainda que acumular muitos *commits* para um *push* possa dificultar o *merge*). Fazendo isso fica muito fácil escrever uma mensagem.

Em geral as pessoas não sabem o que escrever porque é uma lista de coisas. Se a alteração for simples fica fácil escrever algo útil:

- Máscara do CNPJ alterada issue #7643
- Corrigido bug #13456
- Melhorando indentação
- Implementado a interface x conforme documentação y
- Removida as redundâncias
- Refatoração para permitir extensibilidade
- Consertando as khdas do Wallace (ok, essa não pode :) )

Já vi algumas pessoas colocando algum marcador do tipo de alteração: [feature], [refactoring], [style], [bug], [performance], [testing], etc.

Tem que ser sucinto e bem descritivo. Assim **informa bem** e ninguém tem preguiça. Se as pessoas não conseguirem fazer isso, melhor procurar outra profissão.

Claro que se a pessoa não quiser escrever, se ela não tiver uma mínima capacidade de entender o que ela fez ou de se expressar, não tem regra ou ferramenta que dê jeito.

Algumas pessoas gostam de descrever a mudança em profundidade, escrevendo várias linhas. Nada contra, mas isso incentiva as pessoas deixarem pra lá, não funciona bem em todas as equipes.

Em alguns casos uma descrição maior pode ser útil, especialmente para explicar o motivo da mudança. Se for longo demais é melhor documentar separado e apontar para outro local, como nos primeiros exemplos de mensagens que coloquei.

Um usuário precisa começar fazer e ir instruindo os demais. Com o passar do tempo se não houver uma coerência, há problemas na equipe.

Um [exemplo de guia](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que algumas pessoas (programadores) gostaria que o commit não necessitasse de mensagens, kkkkk

Comment: Boa resposta +1. Essa primeira dica de **granular os commits** eu já tinha pensando antes. O difícil é convencer a galera que esse é o melhor caminho (espero que eles não vejam minha pergunta aqui, kkkkkk)

Answer (score 3):

Via de regra, o diff registra exatamente o que/como foi feito, então a mensagem de commit deve:

- registrar o "**porque**" foi feito (incluindo referências a bugs
  pertinentes, etc.);
- e/ou dizer de forma **resumida** a ideia geral do que foi (ou queria ter) feito;

Mas não existe regra geral, cada projeto ou desenvolvedor pode fazer da forma que achar útil, afinal se trata de comunicação por e para humanos. O importante é estabelecer um acordo entre os envolvidos, senão não vai funcionar.

Comment: Caro colega, a pergunta é sobre "uma regra geral", ou melhor sobre "versionamento" e não algo de opinião pessoal, aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas e não opiniões. Se quer deixar uma opinião use o campo de comentários, se não tem pontos para comentar não quer dizer que deve usar a área errada para isto. Entenda como uma critica construtiva e uma orientação.

Comment: A minha resposta foi simples e objetiva. Não existe regra geral "cientificamente comprovada" para mensagens de commit, apenas sugestões, **opiniões** de pessoas mais experientes, sobre como fazer. Por exemplo, o guia referido na outra resposta é para um projeto específico, uma coletânea das opiniões e consensos dos responsáveis por aquele projeto.

Comment: Acho que por ser novo na comunidade ainda não conhece o escopo, ok, entendo que as vezes caimos em opiniões, mas realmente este não é o foco do site e estou apenas lhe dando uma orientação, como eu sendo um membro mais experiente só tive o este intuito, o de lhe ajudar com uma orientação ;)

Comment: Prezado, segue um exemplo de pergunta parecida no site em inglês, note que tem uma resposta muito similar à minha (user 'aku'), sem nenhuma reclamação como a sua. Note também a diversidade de respostas (opiniões/sugestões): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598/suggestions-for-a-good-commit-message-format-guideline

Comment: Não é porque alguem fez algo assim que se deve repetir o ato, você tem que entender que é uma orientação e não uma ordem, presuma sempre boa intenção quando um colega aqui no site lhe der uma orientação. **No entanto** depois da sua ultima edição devo dizer que a resposta ficou razoável, pois o foco realmente é este para uma solução de como usar. Então lhe parabenizo pela ultima edição e espero que tenha entendido tudo o que disse como dicas e que de uma olhada nas páginas Help e META para entender o comportamento esperado no site, até mais ;)