# Quando utilizar o GIT ADD?

Tags: git

Estou com uma dúvida referente a como fazer commits usando GIT.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que eu dei um `git add` em um arquivo e realizei o primeiro commit.
Se eu quiser fazer um commit novamente, preciso usar o comando `git add nome-do-arquivo` novamente, ou só usar o comando para criar novos commits?

Comment: O git-add basicamente adiciona os itens "na lista" de coisas que vão fazer parte do commit. Então, geralmente sempre aplico um git add nos arquivos que quero pra depois fazer o commit. Essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125205/4995) ajuda um a entender melhor porque é importante funcionar assim.

Comment: Olá, alguma das respostas te ajudaram? Se sim, considere marcar o botão ✔️ na resposta aceita.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as diferenças entre os estados dos arquivos do Git (untracked, unmodified, modified, staged)?](/q/326086/112052)

Answer (score 13):

### Resposta resumida:

Sim, o `git add` precisa ser usado. Ele não serve apenas para adicionar os arquivos que ainda não fazem parte do repositório, mas também para indicar quais modificações em arquivos vão entrar no próximo commit.

## Explicando o `git add`

### O Básico

Suponhamos que você tenha um repositório com os arquivos `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` e `d.txt`. Você modificou todos os arquivos, exceto o `d.txt`, que é novo. Se você quiser commitar apenas as modificações do `a.txt` e do `b.txt`, você precisa rodar:

```
git add a.txt b.txt

git commit -m "modificações em a e b"
```

Agora, se você quiser adicionar a.txt, b.txt e incluir o d.txt no mesmo commit, você pode aplicar o `git add a.txt b.txt d.txt`. O próprio git, no momento do commit, vai mostrar quais arquivos foram modificados e quais são novos, se você rodar apenas o comando `git commit`.

### Adicionando todas as modificações no repositório

Quando se usa `git add .` você está basicamente colocando todos os arquivos no mesmo "pacote", para commitar os mesmos em um só commit.

Exemplo:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Modificando todos os arquivos e adicionando d.txt"
```

### Organização dos commits

Geralmente, utilizo o `git add` pra cada arquivo, um por um, pra descrever melhor as modificações que fiz em cada um deles.

Exemplo:

```
git add a.txt
git commit -m "removendo nomes não utilizados"

git add b.txt 
git commit -m "incluindo o campo telefone na lista"
```

### Visualizando o que foi adicionado com `git add`

É possível ainda ver o que foi adicionado na fila para ser commitado a partir do comando `git status`. Ao aplicar o comando `git add` você pode usar `git status` (antes de rodar git commit) e vai ver escrito de verde os arquivos adicionados na fila.

Exemplo:

```bsh
git add .
git status
>>>
En la rama master
Cambios a ser confirmados:
    (usa "git restore --staged <archivo>..." para sacar del área de stage)
    modificado:     a.txt
    modificado:     b.txt
    modificado:     c.txt
    nuevo archivo:  d.txt
```

<sub>Lo siento! Amo espanhol, meu Ubuntu tá configurado pra exibir nesse idioma</sub>

### Exclusão de arquivos

Vale ressaltar que, além do que já foi citado, o `git add` também pode ser chamado pra indicar a exclusão de um arquivo do repositório.

Por exemplo, se você deletar o arquivo c.txt e rodar `git add c.txt` e depois commitar, você está indicando que este arquivo não estará presente no repositório a partir deste commit. Ou seja, ao fazer o pull em outra máquina, o mesmo sería excluido.

Exemplo:

```
rm c.txt
git add c.txt
git commit -m "removendo arquivo antigo"
```

### Forçando inclusão de arquivos presentes no `.gitignore`

É importante citar que, em casos raros, você pode precisar adicionar algo que está no .gitignore. O `git add` por padrão não funciona em arquivos que são ignorados. Mas, caso deseja adicionar um ou mais arquivo num commit específico, você precisa adicionar `-f` como parâmetro.

Assim:

```
  git add arquivo_ignorado.pdf -f
```

Esse parâmetro força a adição do arquivo no "stage" (a lista do que vai pro commit).

### Adicionando arquivos de uma pasta

Se você aplicar o comando `git add` apontando para uma pasta, tudo que existir dentro da mesma será adicionado, exceto o que estiver no `.gitignore`.

Exemplo:

```bsh
mkdir pasta
touch pasta/a.txt pasta/b.txt
git add pasta/
git status
>>>
En la rama master
Cambios a ser confirmados:
    (usa "git restore --staged <archivo>..." para sacar del área de stage)
    nuevo archivo:  pasta/a.txt
    nuevo archivo:  pasta/b.txt
```

#### Desfazendo um `git add`

Você pode desfazer um `git add` com o comando `git reset`. Não entrarei em detalhes, porque já temos esse conteúdo em [Como desfazer um “git add” antes de um commit?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61433/) aqui no site.

#### Modificações após o `git add`

Se você aplicar o `git add` no arquivo `a.txt`, como no nosso exemplo acima, e, depois disso, fizer uma nova modificação, apenas a modificação anterior ficará "guardada" para o próximo commit.

Exemplo:

```bsh
echo "modificação "> a.txt 
git add a.txt 
echo "modificação de novo"> a.txt 
git status
>>>
En la rama master
Cambios a ser confirmados:
  (usa "git restore --staged <archivo>..." para sacar del área de stage)
    modificado:     a.txt

Cambios no rastreados para el commit:
  (usa "git add <archivo>..." para actualizar lo que será confirmado)
  (usa "git restore <archivo>..." para descartar los cambios en el directorio de trabajo)
    modificado:     a.txt
```

Observe que, além do `a.txt` estar adicionado na lista de arquivo que serão commitados, ele aparece novamente na listagem de arquivos modificados. Isso acontece porque, como dito anteriormente, cada `git add` salva na memória as modificações no momento que ele foi chamado.

Isso pode ser útil em caso de você ter feito uma modificação e desejar mandar apenas o que foi feito antes, sem capturar as mudanças depois de ter chamado `git add`.

Se desejar adicionar o arquivo `a.txt` depois de tê-lo atualizado, é necessário novamente chamar `git add a.txt`.

#### Leituras adicionais

- [Diferença entre "git add --all", "git add ." e "git add -u"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326160/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-git-add-all-git-add-e-git-add-u)
- [Diferença do: "git commit -am" e "-m"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344986/diferen%c3%a7a-do-git-commit-am-e-m)
- [Staging Area do GIT é inútil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320129/staging-area-do-git-%c3%a9-in%c3%batil)

Answer (score 5):

Sim, você precisa adicionar as mudanças que você quer no próximo commit, mas você pode usar um atalho:

```
git commit -am [mensagem de commit]
```

Perceba o parâmetro a (minúsculo) ali, ele quer dizer que ele irá adicionar as mudanças de código feitas ao staging e depois será feito o commit.

***Atenção! Esse atalho somente irá funcionar no seguinte cenário:***

- O Arquivo já estiver sendo controlado pelo repositório, ou seja, for uma modificação. Arquivos novos não entram por esse atalho, você irá precisar adicioná-lo usando o próprio comando **add**.

Veja um exemplo:

Na imagem abaixo eu fiz uma modificação em um arquivo que já estava no repositório (1) e criei um novo arquivo (2).

Quando usei o atalho, o commit foi feito no arquivo que já estava "trackeado" pelo repo, mas arquivos que estão com o status **untracked**, não entraram no comando com o atalho de **add**, contiuam fora do repo (3).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, esse atalho é interessante quando se faz manutenções no código. Quando você acrescenta arquivos, use os dois commandos.

Porém, como o git é customizável é possível você escrever uma macro para isso...

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença do: “git commit -am” e “-m”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/344986)